# RStudio: Cleaning data: Remove data with variance below 0.8

Tags: r, data-cleaning, variance

I want to remove data from my dataset called 'data' which shows variance lower than 0.8. I know the following command:

> data[,which(apply(data, 2, var)!=0)]   removes all data (regarding the columns) which has zero variance.

if I wanna do below 0.8, can I simply subsitute the 0 with 0.8? I'm new to R and I'm asking myself if it makes sense, because I'm not sure how to specify that it should remove everything below variance of 0.8.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Try `data[,which(apply(data, 2, var)>=0.8)]`.

Comment: Thank you! Do you know how I can 'check' if it actually removed data with a variance smaller than 0,8?

Comment: Run `apply(data, 2, var)` and see what comes out.